# Очистка адресной строки и добавление значения location.href

Tags: jquery, javascript

Вот часть функции, которая при срабатывании аякса проставляет адрес в браузер.

```
beforeSend : function()
    { history.replaceState({}, document.title, location.href+"?del="+id) }
```

Но нужно, чтобы сналача адрес затирался до site.ru, а потом дописывалось значение.

А то, если получить ответ более одного раза, получается в заголовке такая каша:
`site.ru/message/?del=23?del=22?del=64`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`location.hostname` + `location.pathname` не?